# Caffettiera (Moka Pot) is not making coffee properly

Tags: equipment, coffee

I have fairly large Italian Caffettiera used for making coffee. I think it makes about 8 cups. The thing is it sits on my lit gas stove for at least 15 minutes and nothing comes out.

Any ideas?

PS. Yes, I put water in it ;)

Comment: If you put water in and you're heating water. Water will turn to steam. The pressure has to come out somewhere, where is the steam escaping? The bottom part of it should be contained other than the part that comes up the center...

Comment: When I first glanced at the title of this question, I thought it said, "Cafeteria is not making coffee properly."  My initial response was going to be, "Go to a different cafeteria!"

Answer (score 6):

You may have a broken or loose **gasket**. Separate the two main parts of the caffettiera and check underneath the top part. There should be a large rubber gasket. Over time this gasket gets harder and develops cracks: these cracks let steam and cofee out and prevent the necessary working pressure to build up. If this is your problem, you will notice that the caffettiera hisses and sputters but no coffee comes up.

You should describe what kind of noises your caffettiera is making. On an other tack, are you sure the fire is big/hot enough? If the caffettiera is really large (like, a 16 cups one) and the burner is too small it may be that the pot never gets hot enough to boil.

Lastly, it may be that the caffettiera is so clogged up that water/coffee cannot go through. This would be unusual, and I assume that you have already checked that.

Answer (score 1):

Does steam come out the pressure release on the side? If so, perhaps you've ground your coffee too fine or packed too much of it in. Other than the gasket, as in Walter's answer, that's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Are you puting the water in the bottom part close to the stove? Have you cleaned all parts incl the Coffee Basket, the Gasket, Mesh and Funnel?  You can clean the (inverted) funnel going into the upper chamber (where the coffee should percolate into) with a pipe cleaner.

Put water in the bottom part, coffee in the holder. Twist it together to firm hand tightness and put on the stove.

After this, if you are still having problems getting coffee into the upper chamber, I'd advise going into a store and reading the instructions that come with a new one.